# Volley Request Sets the previous value to TextView

Tags: android, android-volley, http-get

I am trying to understand how volley is used in android, So in my project I am querying a single name from  `http://uinames.com/api/?amount=1`

In the app I have a button that is calling the function to make the request and then set it to the TextView. Also for debug Purposes I am logging the response from the `url`. On the button click the response is correctly seen in the logcat but the text is not set to the TextView until the next time the button is clicked.

Here is the code for the JsonObjectRequest

```
public String getName() {
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            full_name = response.getString(name) + " " + response.getString(last);
                            Log.d(TAG, full_name);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(objectRequest, "");

        return full_name;
    }
```

Following is the Code from the MainActivity that calls the method getName()

```
mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        final RequestClass newReq = new RequestClass();

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                name = newReq.getName();
                mTextView.setText(name);
            }
        });
```

Comment: `String getName()`. An impossible function. getName() cannot return the name. A request is done. And then the function returns immediately. Much later the request is honored and the name is available in `onResonse()`. So redesign your app. You should set the name in the textview in onResponse. Like @Saravinfern tried to tell you. You dont need to use runOnUIthread for it. Make getName() a void function and rename to requestNameAndSet. Make `full_name` a local variable of onResponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens when your function `String getName()` is called:

1. A `JsonObjectRequest` is constructed, and a response and error listeners are passed to the request. Note that the listeners are not executed until their corresponding events happen.
2. The `JsonObjectRequest` is added to the request queue, to be executed when a thread from the thread pool is available.
3. Until now the `full_name` variable has not been touched, and you return the last value that was assigned to it (that's why when you click the button again, you get a name in your text view).
4. Your request gets a response and the listener is called assigning a new value to `full_name` after your function has returned. that is the value that you get on the next call to `getName()`. . .

In general, a function like `getName` can not perform a network operation and return its result immediately. It either needs to *block* until it has the response from the server (and this is [prohibited](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) in android). Or, it can return without the result being fetched yet, and have a callback function (or a listener) that is called with the result when it is available (and this is the the general approach in the Volley library).

That means that you have to `setText` in your response listener. I have noticed that you have a separated class for your network requests `RequestClass`, to keep your design as it is, one solution would be to pass the listeners to `getName()` function (and all other functions that do network stuff in this class), it may look something like this:

```
public void getName(Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener,
                    Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL, null, responseListener, errorListener);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(objectRequest, "");
}
```

And in your activity, you have to pass listeners like this:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) {
        name = newReq.getName(
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String full_name = response.getString("name") + " " + response.getString("last");
                            mTextView.setText(full_name);
                            Log.d(TAG, full_name);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
    }

});
```

As a better design, you may want to avoid passing `Volley` listeners from the activity (which does not have to know anything about `volley`), so you may want to define your own listener interface, override and pass that from the activity to your networking class (where you instantiate your `Response.Listener`, `Response.ErrorListener` and override them to call functions in your listener).

Answer (score 0):

Volley library is deprecated so don't use Volley library.

The best alternative for Volley is RetroFit library.

Comment: this is not an answer to the problem the OP has described.

Comment: but why to use the deprecated items ?

Comment: `Volley library is deprecated`. That is new for me. So young and already passed by.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public void getName() {
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            full_name = response.getString("name") + " " + response.getString("last");

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //Your code to run in GUI thread here
        mTextView.setText(full_name);
    }
    });
                            Log.d(TAG, full_name);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(objectRequest, "");


    } 




mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);



        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getName();

            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `RequestClass` in your code?

Comment: *"Volley always delivers parsed responses on the main thread."*, see official training [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple). No need to use `runOnUiThread`. . .